# Seque and Sequel - is there a term for pairs like these?

Tags: etymology

Seque and Sequel - is there a term for pairs like these? ... verb and noun just a letter (or two?) apart?

(Versus other verb noun pairs which are spelled the same such as 'laugh', 'escape', 'light'. 'finish', 'grin' and 'damage'.)

Comment: What is "seque"?  Can you quote a dictionary definition?

Comment: Why would you assume that *segue* has any relationship to *sequel* aside from the actual letters? (Also note that *segue* is spelled with a ***g***, not a ***q***; as far as I know, there is know such word as *seQue*.)  It's like asking about *an/and* or *the/then*.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica - So you no such a word??

Comment: ROFL! ... I CAN'T SPELL!! Closing question!